# cache implementation using concurrent hashmap

Tags: caching

We have to create a way to find optimum way of cleanup of a cache

For this task, we can say we have cache as ConcurrentHashMap

We have to device a mechanism that we have to delete entries once a certain limit is reached

lets say, 1000 records present in cache

We have to ensure that we delete only those records which are least frequently used

and also, we have to give weightage to the size of the records, as to build bulkier objects, we need more efforts. Thus, we want to preserve them as well.

So we can have a formula where we calculate score

score can be x*size+y*number of time used

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how we can solve this ?

Comment: this whole statements is question how we can code this

Comment: Please read about Caffeine’s design and you can ask questions about it. This is a difficult subject to ask broadly about. https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine